# Override field with custom field and custom form submit in Template Manager

Tags: template-override, form, fields, template-framework

I'm building a new Template for Joomla 3.x and I want to make it easy for the user...

In the template manager I want an 'Upload Photo' file-field. This is no problem; just define it in templateDetails.xml.

However, I would like to save the photo with different sizes under different preset names. The template is a responsive design so I want to use this picture as a background-picture using different sizes for different screen sizes (css using @media (max-width: xxxpx) ).

I know how to use Imagemagick to do the resize and save files to the location I want. But for the life of me I can't find out how and where to:

- override the  for the templateDetails (if necessary)
- override the form submit action

I found :Joomla Override Plugin  but this seems to be outdated.

There is quite a bit of information on overriding on the net but not quite what I'm looking for.

Can anyone help?

Marcel

Comment: After looking at the code some more I presume I need to override : administrator/components/com_templates/controllers/style.php
Where do I put the override?

Comment: As far as I can gather by doing some more searching I can write a plugin with an onExtensionBeforeSave.

Comment: More research... It looks like a plugin for Jform with a onContentAfterSave would do the trick. So I would save the original file and in the onContentAfterSave I would create the resized versions and save them to the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way might be to write a plugin and use the right events:

```
onExtensionAfterSave
```

or

```
onExtensionAfterSave
```

The context would be **"com_templates.style"**.

Example:

```
public function onExtensionAfterSave($context, &$templateTableStyle, $isNew = 0)
{
    if(com_templates.style == 'com_templates_style')
    {
        // do your work ...
    }
}
```

Another way might be to generate the images on-the-fly.

Comment: Shouldn't I write an override for JForm with onContentAfterSave?

Comment: Why should you ?